# How to set status to active in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails3 and I have a user model. This model has a status column. I am showing admin following table

```
Mary approve reject
John approve reject
```

Both approve and reject are links. Since clicking on approve will approve user's record it should not be a get request. It should be a post request. I was thinking to achieve a post request I should make clicking on approve or reject an ajax call.

In the ajax call I would make post call instead of get.

Is this a good strategy? Anyone has any better suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass `:method => 'post'` to your `link_to` call:

```
<%= link_to 'approve', approve_user_path(user), :method => 'post' %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Answer (score 2):

You're right, it shouldn't be a get request. Actually, I think it's neither a post request, because you already have the record and want to change it.

You could just pass `:method => :put` to `link_to`. Rails will make a JS handler and when the link is clicked, it will create an invisible form with `action=PUT` and submit it.

BUT, AJAX is a nice thing too and it's just as hard as setting the method: `:remote => true`

Answer (score 0):

HTTP POST is used for create, and HTTP PUT is used for update.  As such, you should be using doing a PUT (add :method => 'put' to your link_to) since you are updating the user record.  Here's more details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions